# Loading Page Speed Issue in Startup Website

Tags: performance, web

I think the question is a bit silly, but for a newbie startup building a website, do we need to concern the speed of the loading page ? Or what is the stage we need to concern about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always worth thinking about it, but don't spend time trying to make your page load faster if it's time you'd be better off using to make your page more interesting/useful to your users.

Install Firebug and PageSpeed or YSlow and you'll have plenty of information about what you're doing right and what you could be doing better.